# How can a refresh_from_db and a manual get differ?

Tags: python, django

I am currently working on a project I am not very familiar with and trying to remove all of the mentioned reload methods which look like this:

```
def reload(self):
    return self.__class__.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
```

As they were added when `refresh_from_db` wasn't in Django yet, they are all over the place and used to get an updated model from the database. Changing the method to

```
def reload(self):
    self.refresh_from_db()
    return self
```

should in my understanding produce the same output. However when running the tests they fail because there are apparently changes.

What I already investigated is if the `refresh_from_db` method is overwritten, but the model is a regular `django.models.Model`.

EDIT: Example of a failed test

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_modify_child_while_pending (cms.tests.test_publisher.PublishingTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/django-cms/cms/tests/test_publisher.py", line 512, in test_modify_child_while_pending
    self.assertTrue(child.is_published('en'))
AssertionError: False is not true
```

EDIT 2: Testing code

```
def test_modify_child_while_pending(self):
    home = self.create_page("Home", published=True, in_navigation=True)
    child = self.create_page("Child", published=True, parent=home,
                             in_navigation=False)
    home.reload().unpublish('en')

    self.assertPending(child.reload())

    child.refresh_from_db()
    child.in_navigation = True
    child.save()

    # assert draft dirty
    self.assertTrue(child.is_published('en'))
```

Comment: Your first method returns a new instance from the DB and your second method mutates the current instance in-place and returns it, ever so slightly different. Please share your failing tests

Comment: @IainShelvington Thanks, so the only differences would be the changes made to the object, which were not saved in the db? Also I added an example test

Comment: Or changes that were saved to the DB by some other process after the object was fetched. Can you add the actual code for the test?

Comment: @IainShelvington Thanks for the quick responses, added the code in an edit